# Float an icon or div inside a dynamically generated html table that spans a certain number of rows

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a html table that's generated dynamically and trying to place an icon/image in a column on the left side that spans the length of multiple table rows. In my example, I would like to place a single image in the colored shaded areas. This needs to be done using html & css. I'll be using the same icon in each block:

[image]

Here's a sample of the table structure:

```
<table border="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            {dynamic title}
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
           {dynamic description}
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            {dynamic archives}
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my icon div that needs to go in the shaded areas:

```
<div class="icon"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i></div>
```

Obviously, this ain't gonna work:

```
    <table border="0">
   <tbody>
      <div class="icon"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
          <tr>
             <td>
                {dynamic title}
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
               {dynamic description}
             </td>
          </tr>
      </div> 
      <tr>
         <td>
            {dynamic archives}
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could use rowspan from table to span multiple rows.